# Background image not fitting properly in mobile - CSS

Tags: html, css

I am designing a webpage, which has a background image fixed, and i have a problem with it in mobile view. like, In desktop view, its perfectly alright. whereas, in mobile view, the image is too blurred and it is not good looking. i couldn't find where i have made mistake. I have attached images of both the views and my code for background image here.

Desktop:
[image: Desktop_view]

Mobile:
[image: Mobile_view]

My CSS:

```
body 
  {
  font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #ffffff ;
  background-image: url(images/cover3.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  }
```

Comment: I don't see a blurred image in your screen shot of the mobile view, all I see is a black background that looks like no background image at all.

Comment: Try to set `background-size: cover`

Comment: Can you try `background-size: cover`  or    `background-position: center;`    Hope this help.

Comment: Hey All, Thank you, the problem is even after adding your suggestions, I am getting a blurred image of the background in mobile view

Comment: @kshetline Actually even i understood it to be black background. But it is not, When i changed the image which was on purple color, Again the background in mobile is changing to that color with blur image. I cant figure out whats happening

Comment: Hi @DurairajSaro, could you upload another screenshot of the blurred image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query and change  `background-image` or use  `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
html { 
 background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 body{
background: none;
}
```

this fill fit a background for the screen size

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
background-position: center; 
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Lam, the problem is even after adding your suggestions, I am getting a blurred image of the background in mobile view

Comment: Hi @DurairajSaro, does the problem still exist if you use other background images?

Comment: Hi @Andrew Lam, Yes I tried with another image, It is displayed as a blurred image(barely it retain the background color of the image)  in mobile view. It is not black in the above screenshot, It is elongated and blurred image of what i give as background image